# Drupal Login for my Android application?

Tags: 7

How to use drupal login in my android application I want to use the same database that is used in the drupal site.I want to login with the same user name and password that is used in drupal

Please any one help me with this

Answer (score 3):

[Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module allows remote login validation using REST calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex topic and probably too broad of a question.  That said, there was a session about [automatically generating Drupal apps using Phonegap](http://blip.tv/drupalcondenver/auto-generate-your-mobile-drupal-app-using-phonegap-6039133) at Drupalcon Denver 2012.  The beginning of the presentation gives a decent overview of the many different ways in which Drupal can interact with mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the Phonegap and DrupalGap  module, install and set permission for the same and use this code http://code.google.com/p/drupal-phonegap/downloads/list and paste into your assets Directory in your android project  and copy apk file from bin directory and use it in your phone instead of using Emulator

What u need is

1) JDK(6)
2) Eclipse
3) ADT 
4) PhoneGap and DrupalGap modules On your drupal Site

While using this u need to set(append) your Enviornment Variable from this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Hope it will Help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

[DrupalGap](http://www.drupalgap.org) has this feature out of the box. Otherwise you can use the [Services](http://www.drupal.org/project/services) module and the [User Login Resource](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-services-examples).